# Is it safe to alter the Increment ID of historical Magento orders?

Tags: magento

I'm attempting a Magento upgrade from 1.4.0.1 up to latest version (1.9 eventually, although I haven't gotten that far yet).

During the upgrade attempt, foreign key constraint errors are thrown due to about 20 duplicate order numbers going back around 4 years in the shop.

My question is, is it acceptable to go back and modify these orders so that their Increment ID's are unique?  Are there any gotcha's that may trip me up?

I was planning on taking, say, "10003424M20140904" and turning it into "00003424M20140904" on half of the duplicated orders (swapping the first 1 for a 0).

Does anyone know of any reason why this wouldn't work, or if there are any easier ways of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Magento use the order_id if field for internal work. Update increment_id should not break the system.